# How to differentiate between a ZIP file and Microsoft Office file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I would like to differentiate between a ZIP file and a Microsoft Office file (xlsx, docx, pptx) given just the binary string. The first 4 bytes are all `0x504b0304`, but when I tried to use Python's `zipfile` library to read it into memory, it gave an error `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`. I've tried the same code with actual zip files and it works. Does this mean these files are actually Microsoft Office files? Or it could be they are truncated/corrupted?

Is there anyway to identify ZIP file and Microsoft Office files?

Comment: [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) could be a solution for your problem

Comment: The Microsoft Office files with extensions docx, xlsx, pptx are indeed zip files. Not sure why `zipfile` can't read them.

Comment: @Rayne did you find an answer to this problem?

Comment: @PSC Both Zip and MS Office files have the same first 4 bytes `0x504b0304`, but I noticed that MS Office files also have clear strings like `word/fontTable.xml`, `xl/queryTables`, etc. So I used the clear strings as a secondary check. If they're present, then they're MS office files. If not, then they're zip files.